# Spring Boot + Serenity + Cucumber for Rest API Integration Test

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber-serenity

I am using gradle project and I have followed the CucumberSerenity with Spring Boot integration approach by using this link: https://medium.com/@manu.me/bdd-simplified-with-springboot-b56ffdcadb2b
When i run the **gradle task cucumber**,  I get below error message

```
            SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
            java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/internal/Killable
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
                    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:108)
                    at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main.run(Main.java:31)
                    at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main.main(Main.java:19)
            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/internal/Killable
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
                    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
                    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.SupportedWebDriver.<clinit>(SupportedWebDriver.java:31)
                    at net.thucydides.core.configuration.WebDriverConfiguration.lookupSupportedDriverTypeFor(WebDriverConfiguration.java:49)
                    at net.thucydides.core.configuration.WebDriverConfiguration.getDriverType(WebDriverConfiguration.java:33)
                    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.SerenityWebdriverManager.getDefaultDriverType(SerenityWebdriverManager.java:178)
                    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.SerenityWebdriverManager.getWebdriver(SerenityWebdriverManager.java:116)
                    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.ThucydidesWebDriverSupport.getDriver(ThucydidesWebDriverSupport.java:147)
                    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.ThucydidesWebDriverSupport.getPages(ThucydidesWebDriverSupport.java:208)
                    at net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity.getPages(Serenity.java:188)
                    at net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity.getDefaultDependencyInjectors(Serenity.java:84)
                    at net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity.getDependencyInjectors(Serenity.java:74)
                    at net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity.resetDependencyInjectors(Serenity.java:67)
                    at net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity.done(Serenity.java:167)
                    at cucumber.runtime.SerenityObjectFactory.stop(SerenityObjectFactory.java:31)
                    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.disposeBackendWorlds(Runner.java:175)
                    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:70)
                    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:100)
                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:243)
                    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
                    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$3(Runtime.java:100)
                    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
                    at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:204)
                    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1359)
                    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
                    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
                    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
                    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
                    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
                    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
                    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
                    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:101)
                    ... 2 more
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.internal.Killable
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                    ... 46 more
            
            Aug 13, 2020 12:22:47 PM io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime run
            SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
            java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.thucydides.core.webdriver.SupportedWebDriver
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
                    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:108)
                    at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main.run(Main.java:31)
                    at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

**build.gradle**

- Please refer the task cucumber which i am trying to execute from command prompt/terminal

  ```
          buildscript {
              repositories {
                  mavenLocal()
              }
              dependencies{
                  classpath('net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:2.2.9')
              }
          }

          // Apply Plugins & Custom Configurations
          apply plugin: 'java'
          apply plugin: 'maven'
          apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
          apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'

          // Set values from properties
          processResources {
              filesMatching('**/*.properties') { expand(project.properties) }
          }

          // Following two block required for spring boot plugin as no main class
          bootRepackage {
              enabled = false
          }

          project.afterEvaluate {
              if (!project.plugins.hasPlugin(ApplicationPlugin)) {
                  project.plugins.apply(ApplicationPlugin)
                  project.tasks.withType(CreateStartScripts) { CreateStartScripts task ->
                      task.enabled = false
                  }
              }
          }
          // *************************************

          // Java Properties and Depenedencies
          sourceCompatibility = 1.8
          targetCompatibility = 1.8


          //Application Test Source Set and Dependencies
          configurations {
              //providedRuntime
              applicationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile {
                  all*.exclude group: 'com.assertthat', module: 'selenium-shutterbug'
              }
              applicationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
          }

          ext {
              applicationTestBase= "src/applicationTest"
          }

          sourceSets {
              applicationTest {
                  java.srcDir "$projectDir/$applicationTestBase/java"
                  resources {
                      srcDirs = ["$applicationTestBase/resources"]
                  }
                  compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.compileClasspath //+ sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
                  runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath //+ sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
              }
          }

          dependencies {

              applicationTestCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
              applicationTestCompile "com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured"
                  //database dependencies
              applicationTestCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
              applicationTestCompile "com.oracle:ojdbc7"

              //Serenity & Cucumber Dependencies
              applicationTestCompile 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.3.0'
              compile(group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version:'2.4.0') {
                  exclude(module: 'slf4j-api')
              }
              compile ('net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:2.2.9') {
                  exclude group: 'com.google.inject', module:'guice'
                  exclude group: 'io.cucumber', module: 'cucumber-core'
                  exclude group: 'io.cucumber', module: 'cucumber-java'
              }
              compile ('net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:2.2.9'){
                  exclude group: 'io.cucumber', module: 'cucumber-core'
              }
              applicationTestCompile ('net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber5:2.2.5')
              applicationTestCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-single-page-report:2.2.9'
              applicationTestCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-model:2.2.9'
              applicationTestCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:2.2.9'
              applicationTestCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-stats:2.2.9'
              applicationTestCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:2.2.9'
              applicationTestCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:2.2.9'
              applicationTestCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-webdriver:2.2.9'
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-api', version: '3.141.59'
          //    applicationTestCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-api', version: '2.29.1' -- internal/killable
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-remote-driver', version: '3.14.0'
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'htmlunit-driver', version: '2.37.0'
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.141.59'
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-safari-driver', version: '3.141.59'
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-support', version: '3.141.59'
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.14.0'
              applicationTestCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:3.14.0'
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jms', version: '5.1.6.RELEASE'
              applicationTestCompile "com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.0.4.0"
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version:'3.6.2'
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version:'1.5'
              applicationTestCompile group: 'org.apache.maven.plugins', name: 'maven-failsafe-plugin', version: '3.0.0-M5'


          }

          task cucumber() {
              dependsOn assemble, testClasses
              doLast {
                  javaexec {
                      main = "net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main"
                      classpath = configurations.applicationTestRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
                      args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.clean.aggregate', 'src/applicationTest/resources']
                  }
              }
          }

          // Application Test Runners
          task runApplicationTest(type: Test) {
              outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
              include '**/*Runner.java'
              systemProperties(System.getProperties())

              testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.applicationTest.output.classesDir
              classpath = project.sourceSets.applicationTest.runtimeClasspath
              reports.html.destination = project.file("$reports.html.destination/applicationTest")
              reports.junitXml.destination = project.file("$reports.junitXml.destination/applicationTest")
              maxHeapSize = "2G"
              jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'
          }
  ```

**Runner.java** - I have used run with as "CucumberWithSerenity" and used @ActiveProfiles to link with my other

```
          import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
          import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
          import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
          import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
          
          @RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
          @CucumberOptions(features="./src/applicationTest/resources/features/sample.feature", glue={"definitions"}, tags={"@test"},strict = true)
          @ActiveProfiles("test")
          public class Runner{
          }
```

**Definition File**

```
           @SpringBootTest
           public class SampleDefinitions{
           
            @Given("^user sends message\"([^\"]*)\"$")
               public void user_sends_message(String usermessage){
                   System.out.println("usermessage -->"+usermessage);
               }
           }
```

Comment: To Integrate CucumberWithSerenity with Spring Boot need to add the below dependency which picks all the SpringBoot annotations & etc from java files. **('net.serenity-bdd:serenity-spring:2.2.9')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when classes aren't available at runtime.

You are using custom sourcesets i.e. `applicationTest` which is not configured properly to run cucumber task.

One solution is to change your class path in cucumber task and include the main source sets to use applicationTest classes

1. cucumber task

```java
classpath = sourceSets.applicationTest.runtimeClasspath
```

2. sourcesets

```java
main {
    compileClasspath += applicationTest.output
    runtimeClasspath += applicationTest.output
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is this spring, cucumber/ghjerkin library to easily test sprint rest api: https://github.com/RedFroggy/spring-cucumber-rest-api